# Time complexity of ArrayList traversal

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am working on a program that may use either array data structure or ArrayList class. I want to know in which case will my access to the element be faster, array or ArrayList.
For e.g if 'a' is an array and 'b' is an ArrayList both of type Integer, 'c' is any integer variable, which of the following statement will execute faster?

```
c=a[10];
c=b.get(10);
```

Comment: It would be **very** simple to write a benchmark ... and this would allow you to also benchmark different VM implementations too .. since they're not all equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in constant time.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: what about the other question, which is faster??

Comment: Obviously, an array also runs in constant time. Therefore, they should be roughly equivalent (although, the array `a` in your case should run a tiny bit faster). Assuming all you're doing is accessing, treat them as the same.

Comment: @PiyushVishwakarma ArrayList, though implemented using an array, ArrayList would theoretically be "slower" through possible overhead due to the extra get method call, although it's most likely insignificant when compared to what action you are doing against every element while iterating, and when compared to the cost of having more complex code by using a basic array. You can check this yourself by looking at the code of get, and seeing what extra logic is executed until the actual retrieval from the array.